# TOC ArcGIS JS API app Is empty

Tags: table-of-contents, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I've been trying to use [Nliu's TOC](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=9b6280a6bfb0430f8d1ebc969276b109) . I've followed a few examples and looked through the threads here, but I'm totally stumped on why my code isn't working.

This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Emerald Oil War Map</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../vendors/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/esri/css/esri.css">

  <style>
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 90%;
    }



    #leftpane {
        width: 280px;
        overflow: auto
    }

    #map{
    padding:0;
    }

    /* this line hide layers when out of scale for the inline TOC */
            .agsjsTOCOutOfScale {
            /*  display: none;*/
    }
  </style>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var djConfig = { 
        parseOnLoad: true,
        packages: [{
          "name": "agsjs",
          "location": "http://localhost:7931/gentelella/vendors/agsjs/build/agsjs"
        }]
       };          
  </script> 

  <script src="../vendors/arcgis_js_api/library/3.15/init.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map, toc, dynaLayer1;

    require(["dojo/_base/connect",
             "dojo/parser",
             "dojo/on",
              "agsjs/dijit/TOC",
             "esri/map",
             "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
             "esri/geometry/Extent",
             "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer",
             "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
             "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
             "dijit/registry",
             "dojo/domReady!"],
             function (connect, parser, on, TOC, Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer, Extent, registry) {

                 //call the parser to create the layout dijits
                 parser.parse();

                 initExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({
                     "xmin": 5091493,
                     "ymin": 4570327,
                     "xmax": 5192700,
                     "ymax": 4616189,
                     "spatialReference": {
                         "wkid": 102100
                     }
                 });
                 map = new Map("map", {
                     extent: initExtent,

                     basemap: "osm"
                 });


                 TarheJamedynamicMapServiceLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://192.178.28.33:6080/arcgis/rest/services/tarhjame_1/MapServer", {
                     "opacity": 0.5

                 });



                 TarheJamedynamicMapServiceLayer.on("load", function (evt) {

                     toc = new TOC({
                         map: map,
                         layerInfos: [{
                             layer: TarheJamedynamicMapServiceLayer,
                             title: "BOE30"
                         }]
                     }, 'tocDiv');
                     toc.startup();

                 });
                 map.addLayer(TarheJamedynamicMapServiceLayer);
             }
            );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div id="content" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;">



            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="leftPane" region="left" splitter="true">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" style="height: 300px;">

                    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="Table of Contents" selected="true">
                        <div id="tocDiv">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="center">




            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" look like?